# RegEx to exclude a string

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following strings in my application.

```
/admin/stylesheets/11

/admin/javascripts/11

/contactus
```

what I want to do is to write a regular expression to capture anything other than string starting with 'admin'

basically my regex should capture only

```
/contactus
```

by excluding both

```
/admin/stylesheets/11

/admin/javascripts/11
```

to capture all i wrote

```
/.+/
```

and i wrote `/(admin).+/` which captures everything starts with 'admin'. how can i do the reverse. I mean get everything not starting with 'admin'

thanks in advance

cheers

sameera

EDIT - Thanks all for the answers

I'm using ruby/ Rails3 and trying to map a route in my routes.rb file

My original routes file is as followss

```
match '/:all' => 'page#index', :constraints => { :all => /.+/ }
```

and i want the RegEx to replace /.+/

thanks

Comment: What language/regular expression implementation do you use?

Comment: Is this all the regular expression is doing? If so, you're better off looking for a built-in function like `string.beginswith()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the language/regular expression implementation you are using supports [look-ahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can do this:

```
^/(?!admin/).+/
```

Otherwise, if you only can use basic syntax, you will need to do something like this:

```
^/([^a].*|a($|[^d].*|d($|[^m].*|m($|[^i].*|i($|[^n].*)))))
```

Comment: @marcog: It depends on the language/regular expression implementation if delimiters like `/` are required.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the `/`'s as regex delimiters. Re-read the question and it makes sense now. +1